# redis keys not being expired

Tags: ruby, redis

```
irb(main):001:0>  redis_key = User.create_prev_order_in_progress_redis_key(194652)
    => "prev_order_in_progress_194652"
irb(main):002:0> $redis_secondary.get(redis_key)
    => "1"
irb(main):003:0> $redis_secondary.ttl(redis_key)
    => 0
```

I have moved my `redis` server to a new server so that's probably why
But I have no idea why these keys are not nil even though the *ttl* is 0.

`redis` version is 2.8.3

Comment: The issue was with the move. The old master was defined as slave. and it didn't the delete the keys.

Comment: I believe you should form this comment into an answer, for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the move. The old master was defined as slave. and it didn't the delete the keys.